# Kivy apk built by buildozer crashes soon after displaying presplash screen

Tags: python, kivy, apk, buildozer

I am new to Kivy and using buildozer. However, I've followed the instructions from buildozer.readthedocs and run "buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt" as best as I can, yet, apk crashes immediately after displaying presplash screen. On examining my_log.txt there is no "Traceback...".

I have searched google for any leads to remedy the issue I am facing but to no avail. Any suggestion to workaround would be appreciated.

The python side code in main.py is:

```
import kivy

kivy.require('2.0.0')

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout


from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

# adding custom font
# for now place the ttf in root directory
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
LabelBase.register(name="CamingoCode",
    fn_regular="CamingoCode-Regular.ttf")

# point to images.kv for design
Builder.load_file('m_screen.kv')

class MainLayout(MDBoxLayout):
    pass


class MedinfoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # set background to white, can be overridden in .kv
        #Window.clearcolor = (1,0,0,1)
        self.theme_cls.primary_pallete = "DeepOrange"
        self.icon = 'images/medinfo_logo.png'
        return MainLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MedinfoApp().run()
```

The .kv file named 'm_screen.kv' is:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
#:import images_path kivymd.images_path
<Image>:
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: False
<MDLabel>:
    markup: True
    font_name: "CamingoCode"


<MainLayout>:
    # MedinfoApp
    # BoxLayout defined in main.py
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 0
        spacing: 0
        # height: "200dp"
        height: root.height/4
        size_hint_y: None
        
        

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0,1,0,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        
        MDCarousel:
            direction: 'right'
            loop: True
            Image:
                source: 'images/3.jpg'
            Image:
                source: 'images/2.jpg'
            Image:
                source: 'images/1.jpg'


    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        padding: 0#[0,0,2,0] #l,t,r,b
        size_hint:(1, None)
        height: "30dp"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        MDIcon:
            icon: 'account'
        # Image:
        #   size_hint: (None, 1)
        #   # width: "20dp"
        #   width: root.width/20
        #   source: 'images/medinfo_logo.png'
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Electronic Medical Records'
            color: (20,0,0,1)
            bold: True
            halign: "left"
            valign: "middle"
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            width: root.width*3.5/4
            text_size: self.size

        Button:
            text: 'open'

            
    # horizontal line separating page title and 
    # remaining selections          
    
    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 3
        # adaptive_width: True
        padding: 25
        spacing: 15

        
        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            elevation: 11
            padding: "25dp"
            size_hint: .2, .4
            pos_hint: {'center_x':  .5, 'center_y:': .5}
            # MDIcon:
            #   icon: 'account-heart'
            Image:
                source: 'images/patient.png'
                allow_stretch: False
                keep_ratio: False
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Patient'
                font_name: "CamingoCode"
                halign: 'center'

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            elevation: 11
            padding: "25dp"
            size_hint: .25, .4
            pos_hint: {'center_x':  .5, 'center_y:': .5}
            Image:
                source: 'images/appointment_list.png'
                allow_stretch: False
                keep_ration: False
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Appointment List'
                halign: 'center'
        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            elevation: 11
            padding: "25dp"
            size_hint: .25, .4
            pos_hint: {'center_x':  .5, 'center_y:': .5}
            Image:
                source: 'images/patient_add.png'
                allow_stretch: False
                keep_ration: False
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Add Patients'
                halign: 'center'

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            elevation: 11
            padding: "25dp"
            size_hint: .25, .4
            pos_hint: {'center_x':  .5, 'center_y:': .5}
            Image:
                source: 'images/appointment_add.png'
                allow_stretch: False
                keep_ration: False
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Add Appointment'
                halign: 'center'
        

    MDBottomAppBar:
        md_bd_color: 0,1,0,1
        MDToolbar:
            
            icon: 'images/medinfo_logo.png'
            type: 'bottom'
            mode: "center"
```

and buildozer.spec is:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = MedInfo

# (str) Package name
package.name = medinfo

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.medinfo.pk

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ttf

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = chardet,cython,docutils,idna,Kivy,Kivy-Garden,kivymd,Pillow,pip,Pygments,python3,requests,setuptools,urllib3,wheel

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/images/512x512.jpg

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/images/medinfo_logo.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.0.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 30

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = False

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) disables the compilation of py to pyc/pyo files when packaging
# android.no-compile-pyo = True

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: Attach full log please.

Comment: Thank you @Neizvestnyj for getting back. I examined the apk in Android Studio and found out that Kivy language that was being asked for was 2.0.0 whereas the installed version was 1.16.1. 

So I deleted .buildozer folder and re-executed buildozer -y android run command. And it worked out fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in `kivy` version. `kivy 2.0.0` has a bug. So the best version is `kivy 2.0.0rc4`. You should download in plugins trough settings. And in your `buildozer.spec` `requirements` you should specify the version of `kivy` like this:

```
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is a problem with one or more dependent library. Kivy does not work well with all dependent packages on Android, even if you list them within requirements.

Some of Python packages may require recipes. Here is list of recipes developed so far:
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes

In your case you should get answer running your app with logcat.
Uncomment follwong line in buildozer.spec

```
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D
```

then build, deploy and run via ADB with:

```
buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat
```

BTW. If you see message "Could not extract private data" on splash screen, is probably becasue of Pygments requirement. Try to remove it from requirements list.

Comment: I am getting the "Could not extract private data" on the splash screen, but I don't have the pygments requirement. I don't know what other errors there are.

Comment: You probably used another incompatible requirement listed in your buildozer.spec. What you specified within requirements parameter?

Comment: These are my requirements: 'requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4,requests,matplotlib,pandas,numpy,bs4,pandas_datareader,kivycalendar3,datetime,transformers,torch,KivyCalendar'